# Saving all browsers urls history

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, logging, browser

I need to write a log system that will save all the domain names and time of visit (if possiable the closing time too) that was made using all browsers which are installed on windows.

for example:
http://stackoverflow.com 14:45 - 16:55

I couldnt find any implementation info on google, Please forward me or explain what is the way to go.

Comment: what you ask for is highly dependent on browser/browser version used (and potentially Windows version too)...  what exactly have you tried ?

Comment: I need to support all browsers - all version and future version - i though that maybe working with browsers are not good solution. and started to think about monitoring ip - what do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you ask for is highly dependent on browser/browser version used (and potentially Windows version too)...

Since you don't describe what the goal is it is hard to come up with specific solutions/options...

One rather browser-agnostic option would be to implement a proxy and configure the system/browsers to use that proxy... the proxy would then do the logging. but this could easily be circumvented by changing the proxy configuration in the browser...

Comment: +1. Proxy (especially if you can alter network configuration to make it also the only point to access internet from machines you are interested) is good approach... Also it is unclear what is the goal of the question as both approaches are implemented multiple times already...

Comment: proxy is little problematic solution cause it can be easily disabled by user - i need solution that only admin will be able to set - proxy can be removed by regular user.

Answer (score 1):

See if you can read the history files for each browser and parse the details from there.

CHROME:

in xp = C:\Documents and Settings\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\
in vista =  C:\users\USER\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\

FIREFOX: 
C:\Documents and Settings\owner\Local Settings\History

IE:
C:\Documents and Settings\YOURUSERNAME\Local Settings\History

I have never tried this an don't know if the history is stored encrypted, and what level of details (time opened, time closed etc) are stored.

Comment: I need to support all browsers - all version and future version - i though that maybe working with browsers are not good solution. and started to think about monitoring ip - what do you think?